# Which IDEA files belong in version control?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA creates a bunch of files in `.idea/`. Which ones need to be in version control?

I found the following suggested `.gitignore` entries:

```
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf
```

Currently have the following in version control - are all of these necessary?

```
./idea/misc.xml
./idea/modules.xml
./idea/vcs.xml
```

And IDEA just created this file and added it to version control, where it seems to me like it does not belong?

```
.idea/uiDesigner.xml
```

Comment: Easy way to find out: open up the file and see what's in it. If it's specific to your application, commit it.

Comment: @3Dave Not really. Most of them are specific to my application, but many of them are also specific to the current user, and some seem to be possible to delete entirely without any problem.

Comment: Did you see [this document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a couple of years I was a supporter of using a specific `.gitignore` for IntelliJ with [this suggested configuration](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).

**Not anymore.**

IntelliJ is updated quite frequently, internal config file specs change more often than I would like and JetBrains flagship excels at auto-configuring itself based on maven/gradle/etc build files.

So my suggestion would be to leave **all editor config files out of project** and have users configure editor to their liking. Things like code styling can and should be configured at build level; say using **[Google Code Style](https://github.com/google/google-java-format)** or **[CheckStyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)** directly on Maven/Gradle/etc.

This ensures consistency and leaves editor files out of source code that, in my personal opinion, is where they should be.

Comment: I agree with this. All my IntelliJ projects use Maven or sbt and I don't check in any IntelliJ project files. All important settings are handled by Maven/sbt, and IntelliJ can pick them up from there.

Comment: Inspiring. Would this imply git-ignoring all of `.idea`, `*.ipr`, `*.iml` and `*.iws` (for IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2)?

Comment: @Anonymous been doing that for several years now with zero issues, in fact, if the developers are free to choose their IDE of choice (which I honestly think makes sense) ignoring IDE specific files, is beneficial...